# Error passing pointers in Xcode, but works in Codeblocks on windows

Tags: c++, macos, vector, codeblocks

When I run the following C++ code from CodeBlocks on Windows using the mingw compiler, all is fine. But, when I run it on Mac OS X it doesn't work:

```
void func (vector<int> &v1, vector<vector< int *> > &v2);

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(0);
    vector<vector <int *> > v2;
    vector<int *> vTemp;
    int x = 0;
    int * ptr = &x;
    vTemp.push_back(ptr);
    v2.push_back(vTemp);

    func(v1,v2);
    cout<<*(v2[0][1])<<endl;

    return 0;
}
void func (vector<int> &v1, vector<vector< int *> > &v2)
{
    v1.push_back(1);
    int *ptr = &(v1[1]);
    v2[0].push_back(ptr);
    cout<<*(v2[0][1])<<endl;
    v1.push_back(2);
    int *ptr2 = &(v1[2]);
    v2[0].push_back(ptr2);
    v1.push_back(3);
    int *ptr3 = &(v1[3]);
    v2[0].push_back(ptr3);
}
```

The output I expect (and get on Windows) is

```
1
1
```

But on the Mac, I get

```
1
0
```

Does anyone have any idea why this should be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is invalid, and you're seeing undefined behavior. Your pointer value holds the address of a vector element which may be invalid after the `vector` resizes.

Running the program with GuardMalloc enabled catches this for you.

Comment: To expand on this, the program does `int *ptr = &(v1[1])` and then it does `v1.push_back(2)`. `push_back` may invalidate all pointers pointing at elements of the vector if it requires increasing the vector's capacity. If you add a line `v1.reserve(4);` in `main` after you create `v1` then you'll have enough capacity and you'll get your expected answer. Of course it's still a bad idea to store pointers this way because it's so fragile.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and thanks bames53 for clarifying. I thought there must be some undefined behaviour but I couldn't see where it was coming from. So pointers to objects in a vector is a bad idea, right?

Comment: @Edlennion you're welcome. they're not a bad idea - i use them in restricted scopes/contexts to avoid this problem. remember, your element accesses via `[]` and `at()` and even iterators also use pointers (in some form). pointers and references are *required* to make the collection useful as-is. your program adds a dimension of complexity to that, and takes a little time to get used to knowing what to look out for but this level of complexity exists in the real world and it is *not necessarily bad*. at times, it's the best solution, but there are dangers (as you now know).